# angular ui bootstrap datepicker filter with repeater

Tags: angularjs

i am new to angularjs and i am getting problem at the repeat filter with bootstrap date-picker ng-model (dt | date:'yyyy-MM-dd') with date (create_at).

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{create_at:{'dt| date:"yyyy-MM-dd"'},     subject:query}" class="thumbnail">
...
</li>
```

Thanks!

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? filter by date?

Comment: yes, i am wondering is there a way to convert the ng-model (dt) to a string format in 'yyyy-MM-dd' which can compare with my date (create_at) ? dt ng-model seems return a date object, i tried {dt |date:'yyyy-mm-dd'} seems work find on the output but its not working when i put into the repeat filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create a custom filter for that, the date filter is a formatter, it will not filter your results so what you need to do is something like: (this is for date range but you can convert it to a single date):

```
   app.filter("dateRange", function() {
  return function(items, from, to) {
        var df = parseDate(from);
        var dt = parseDate(to);
        var result = [];        
        for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
            var tf = new Date(items[i].date1 * 1000),
                tt = new Date(items[i].date2 * 1000);
            if (tf > df && tt < dt)  {
                result.push(items[i]);
            }
        }            
        return result;
  };
```

in view:

```
  <lin g-repeat="order in orders | dateRange:dateFrom:dateTo">
...
</li>
```

so you see here, we get a date string, convert it to a date and then filter by the date range. you can modify it as you please... you can also turn dates to ISO or whatever

Comment: I got your idea ... Thanks Jony !  try on that now

Comment: i got the filter running but then i got error that " cannot read property form items.length". My guess is the filter run before the items array ready and items array is getting from $http.get in main controller. What is the best way to avoid this ?  plunker for reference http://plnkr.co/edit/pTCsDR9lB4zErP7akkes?p=preview

Comment: your plunker is kinda broken...  but I just do a lo dash check for items like if (!_.isEmpty(items)) {...}, so the filter does not return anything if items is empty otherwise it runs the check... and returns the values...